# Role Hierarchy Developer Certification Question

Tags: role-hierarchy, roles, dev401

Hoping some good Samaritan(s) who happens to be Salesforce developer experts could weigh in on the answer to this question as I am unsure:

For objects where data access is granted through the role hierarchy, how is access granted?

a.  Users are only granted read access to data owned by users above them in the role hierarchy

b.  Users are granted access to data accessible by users below them in the role hierarchy

c.  Users are granted access to data accessible to users in the same role in the role hierarchy

d.  Users are only granted access to data owned by users below them in the role hierarchy

I believe the answer should be (b) but a practice exam says the answer is (d)? Please confirm that it's (b) and that (d) is wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is (d) - as if often the case with these exam questions the wording is the key.

Here the key part is the phrase "For objects where data access is granted through the role hierarchy". You are correct that in the following scenario access is rolled up.

Lets take an example we have a role for Sales Manager and a role for Sales Team Member (with Manager being above member in the hierarchy). Alice is a Sales Team Manager and Bob is a Member of her Sales Team. Bob is working on the ACME Account which has a related record of an object called "Secret_Details__c" which he needs to see. Charles the office data manager shares this record with Bob to help him close his Sale. Bob can see this as it is manually shared to him (but owned by Charles). Alice can see this (as correctly pointed out in the comments) as she is above Bob and also gains his special permissions (which include access to this record).

However for an object where access is controlled via the role hierarchy only the users are granted access to data owned by those below them in the hierarchy. This is reading from the question that the OWD is private and access is granted via the hierarchy only.

AS we have seen, even after getting the certificate and playing with SFDC for many years - the wording of these exams can still catch you out if you don't pay attention.

I would (still) recommend watching [this video from Shell Black](http://www.shellblack.com/whiteboard/security-owds-sharing-rules-and-the-role-hierarchy/) for a good overview of sharing.

Comment: Thanks pbattisson - but I have tested in my sandbox and my production org (late at night) that in the same described situation, if another person shares an account through account team to allow Bob to have access to an account, Alice would also gain access to that account because of Bob being added to the Account Team of an account that he was not supposed to have access to.

Comment: I did watch the Shell Black video multiple times before - if you fast forward to between minute 4:00 to 4:55 of the Shell Black video - he even says that "you ALSO inherit the special privileges that has been given to User who is below you" on the Roles Hierarchy.

Comment: Updated to give the correct answer - these tricky worded questions can still catch out the best of us.

Comment: the correct answer still seems (b), because although the question states access "is granted through the role hierarchy", nowhere in the question has it been stated that access is ONLY granted through the role hierarchy and in no other means. And if access is granted by other means, teams etc, (d) immediately becomes false, the keyword here is "data accessible" vs "data owned".